# JavaFX binding to Media source attribute

Tags: java, javafx-8

hopefully I can get some help with this. I am trying to bind the string variable to a the source attribute in FXML.

The FXML looks like this below

```
<MediaView fx:id="media" x="0" y="200" fitHeight="800" fitWidth="1000" visible="true">
            <mediaPlayer>
                <MediaPlayer fx:id="videoPlayer" autoPlay="false"   >
                    <media>
                        <Media fx:id="currentlyPlaying" source="${controller.songURL}"/>
                    </media>

                </MediaPlayer>
            </mediaPlayer>
        </MediaView>
```

This gives me the error:

Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Cannot bind to untyped object.

Clearly caused because I tried to bind to the reference item.

What is a preferred way to accomplish this (I understand that is a relative term and I apologize)  so that I can have the file play more than just one sample video?

Thanks!

**Edited title, was typed in a hurry. I have been working on this for a bit. so far no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`source` is not a writable property in `Media`: it is a final value settable only via the constructor. Consequently there is no way to bind it (because it can't change). Similarly, `media` is a constant value in `MediaPlayer`.

So you need to arrange to bind the `MediaView`'s `mediaPlayer` property to the controller's `songURL` property. I don't see any way to do this in FXML: you need to do it in the controller's `initialize()` method. Something like

```
media.mediaPlayerProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
    Media m = new Media(songURL.get());
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(m);
    player.setAutoPlay(false);
    return player ;
}, songURL));
```

(assumes you have a `StringProperty songURL` defined in the controller).

Then you just remove the content of the `<MediaView>` tag in the FXML:

```
<MediaView fx:id="media" x="0" y="200" fitHeight="800" fitWidth="1000" visible="true">
</MediaView>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes perfect sense the way that you explained it.